# How can I smoothly move my character in babylon.js?

Tags: javascript, babylonjs

Now I turn it like this:

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    if(isStart && e.keyCode == 37 || e.keyCode == 65)
    {
        this.player.position.x > -1 ? this.player.position.x -= 1.2 : ''
        this.camera.position = new BABYLON.Vector3(this.player.position.x, 2, -35)
    }
    
    if(isStart && e.keyCode == 39 || e.keyCode == 68)
    {
        this.player.position.x < 1 ? this.player.position.x += 1.2 : ''
        this.camera.position = new BABYLON.Vector3(this.player.position.x, 2, -35)
    }
})
```

As you can see I have a space constraint. It should be so. But now my character is very sharply (instantly) to the left or right. How do I fix this?

Comment: You should probably use a BABYLON.ActionManager.OnKeyDownTrigger from [this page](https://doc.babylonjs.com/divingDeeper/events/actions) instead of a document.addEventListener and also you should use an [interpolate value action](https://doc.babylonjs.com/typedoc/classes/babylon.interpolatevalueaction). Just some tips. I'm now going to delete my answer since it was of pretty poor quality and very rough...

Answer (score 0):

I use a own game loop in my projects. (e.g.  mainloop.js on github) In draw calls I do the scene rendering (scene.render()) and in update calls I calculate game logic (like positioning).  The integrated babylonjs is disabled (engine.stopRenderLoop())

In your key down logic I would set up the target location, in the update logic of the mainloop you could calculate the steps in between. (the steps from origin position till the target location) The render process in based on the actual calculated position, independed if you run with a slow or high frame rate.

You could also try to use babylonjs animation logic.